# taking top fifty items in sorted vector into another vector (clojure)

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

EDITED because question is about same program.

I'm trying to take the top fifty items in the first vector and write them to the topfifty variable, to return to use elsewhere.

```
 "gets the closest 50 locations in the file fName and writes them out by sending a function     to the agent"
  [fName]
  (let [sorted (sort-by sortFn (makeStructs fName))
        topFifty ;TODO take the top 50 from sorted 
        ]
```

How exactly do I do this in clojure? I'm new to the language and have never used lisp. I'd rather not use a for loop as that is not exactly functional-ish.

Comment: Now that you have removed your previous question and replaced it with a different one, my original answer makes no sense at all. If you have a new question, it is best to start a new question.

Comment: @dfan: sorry. In the past I have been told not to start a new question when the question is about the same program.

Comment: who told you that? I think you should ignore them. This site is about answering programming questions. If you have two separate questions about two separate issues, then make them into two separate questions. If they are closely related, you may choose to include them in the same question, but feel free to break them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the new question (the question that my other answer was in response to has been replaced): `(take 50 sorted)` will return the first 50 elements of `sorted`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like `(apply struct storeinfo vals)`, where `vals` is the result of your split. This unpacks all of the values in `vals` into a call to `(struct storeinfo ...)`, which creates a `storeinfo` from initial values in the same order as its definition.

Comment: Thanks. What will this storeinfo struct be named, so that I can use it in the return statement?  Also, that split that I have above doesn't work for some reason. I get an exception whenever I run the program. Do you know what might be wrong with it?

Comment: I assume you're trying to split the "input" so you should have (split input #",")

Comment: You don't need to name it, if it's the last statement in your function. If you need to name it just do it in the usual way: `(let [my-struct (apply ...)] ...)`. I don't know offhand what is wrong with your split, although you don't seem to be passing it the string you are trying to split, so that's the first place to start.